# How to scrape text from tooltips generated with javascript

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I've written the following code to get the positions of all blue markers in the map.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()

url="https://emf2.bundesnetzagentur.de/karte/Default.aspx?lat=52.4107723&lon=14.2930953&zoom=14"
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render(sleep = 3)
data = r.html.html

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
BlueTriangles = soup.find_all(src="images/funk_hf.png")
for Triangle in BlueTriangles[1:]:
    TriangleStyle = Triangle['style']
    PixelPosition = TriangleStyle.split('transform: translate3d(')[1].split(', 0px); z')[0]
    print(PixelPosition)

r.session.close()
```

When I open the URL using a web browser, I see that each blue marker has a unique ID that is shown in a tooltip on mouseover:

[image]

The html code of the tooltip appears to be rendered triggered by a mouseover event:

[image]

Is there any way of scraping the the ID from the tooltip? I was wondering whether it is possible use the script parameter of render to force a mouseover event. But I couldn't find a way to integrate it in the code:

```
$('#foo').trigger('mouseover');
```

Comment: I recommend using https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ instead of the string functions you are currently using. With Beautifulsoup it'll be easy to extract what you want from the page.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've removed the string functions to make it more clear and to keep the focus on answering the question in the post, which remains unanswered.

Comment: Hm, it looks like the whole map is rendered in Javascript. So I believe you'd have to work with some headless browser like Scrapy or Selenium in order to get the Javascript executed. Even then it might be hard to extract all the ids.

Comment: requests_html is rendering the Javascript of the map. Only the tooltips seems not be rendering on the initial page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Points on the map are rendered by request to the endpoint https://emf2.bundesnetzagentur.de/karte/Standortservice.asmx/GetStandorteFreigabe with box coordinates (in this case `{"Box":{"sued":52.39231101879802,"west":14.248666763305664,"nord":52.42927461241364,"ost":14.337587356567385}}`).

Response is json.  Locations' data is encrypted by AES. Decryption code is available in js script loading with page (functions **CryptParams** and **DecryptData**).

After decryption we get this nice data:
`"[{"Titel":"018126","Lng":14.311666,"Lat":52.428888,"fID":1076,"sonderseite":false},{"Titel":"011720","Lng":14.259722,"Lat":52.423054,"fID":2196,"sonderseite":false},{"Titel":"87011082","Lng":14.275832,"Lat":52.401666,"fID":560919,"sonderseite":false}]"`

You have two ways.

1. Use selenium or similar software to render JS and try to parse resulting DOM;
2. Write parser to send request to GetStandorteFreigabe endpoint and decode it's response (convert code from js to python),